# Reference to 'send_byte' is ambiguous,

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, arduino, virtual

I'm making a libary for an RF-module for the arduino. I'm almost done with my code, when i got one error that i don't know how to solve. 
The error happens in this piece of code:

```
#include "Rf_module.hpp"

class send;
class receive;

class whatsapp : public send, public receive
{
private:
    hwlib::target::pin_in_out &whatsapp_pin; 
public:
    whatsapp(hwlib::target::pin_in_out &whatsapp_pin, int frequency):
        send (whatsapp_pin, frequency),
        receive (whatsapp_pin, frequency),
        whatsapp_pin( whatsapp_pin )
    {}

    void send_text(char text[], int length)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i< length-1; i++)
        {
            int ascii_value = text[i];
            send_byte(ascii_value);
```

The error is: reference to 'send_byte' is ambiguous.
My code is structure in a few classes starting with a partly abstract class communication.

```
#include "hwlib.hpp"

class communication
{
protected:
    hwlib::target::pin_in_out & current_pin;
    int sending_frequency;
public:
    communication(hwlib::target::pin_in_out & current_pin, int sending_frequency);
    virtual void send_bit(int bit);
    virtual int get_bit();
virtual void get_startbit() = 0;
virtual void send_startbit() = 0;
virtual int get_byte() = 0;
virtual void send_byte(int byte) = 0;
};
```

Then there is also a send and receive class for the RF-module itself.

```
#include "hwlib.hpp"
#include "communication.hpp"


class send : public communication
{
public: 
    send(hwlib::target::pin_in_out & current_pin, int sending_frequency);
    void send_startbit() override;
    void send_byte(int byte) override;
    void test_send();

class receive : public communication
{
public:
    receive(hwlib::target::pin_in_out & current_pin, int sending_frequency); 
    void get_startbit() override;
    int get_byte() override;
    void test_receive();
};
```

My main looks like this;

```
#include "hwlib.hpp"
#include "whatsapp.hpp"

int main(void)
{
    auto pin = hwlib::target::pin_in_out(1,17);
    pin.direction_set_output();

    whatsapp sender(pin,10);
    sender.test_send();


    return 0;
}
```

The hwlib libary that is included in a lot of the files is the libary that my teacher gave to work with the arduino, its pretty standard in that it lets you use the pins and a few other freatures. I hope you guys have enough information
that you can maybe help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
class whatsapp : public send, public receive
```

You are using multiple inheritance, and both would have implementation of `send_byte` and hence the error. You need to specify via which class:

```
void send_text(char text[], int length)
{
    ...
            send::send_byte(ascii_value);
```

But this seems to bad design!